# getting list value to show as title in slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using bjqs slider plugin to slide some content, currently apart from next and previous buttons there is a navigation which helps user to choose desired slide, what I want to do is to show Slide's title instead of numbers.
This plugin Uses `<ul>` and each list Item is going to be one slide, So, I was wondering If I can get value from `<li>` element and put it instead of numbers.

Here is the code that generates numbers:

```
 var conf_markers = function() {
    // create a wrapper for our markers
    $m_wrapper = $('<ol class="bjqs-markers"></ol>');

    // for every slide, create a marker
    $.each($slides, function(key, slide){

        var slidenum    = key + 1,
            gotoslide   = key + 1;

        if(settings.animtype === 'slide'){
            // + 2 to account for clones
            gotoslide = key + 2;
        }

        var marker = $('<li><a href="#">'+ slidenum +'</a></li>');
```

Comment: I'm not sure since I can't see all of the code, but it looks like it uses that `<a>` text/html value `slidenum` later on to trigger the event, and then show that specific Slide. You might have to store that num in `data-slide=""` or something, and change a bunch of other code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the above code with this and see if it works. I just glanced at the slider code on github and in theory this should work. `$slides` should refer to the `<li>` that contains the image with the title.

**EDIT**

```
$.each($slides, function(key, slide){
    var slidenum    = key + 1,
        slidename   = $(slide).find('img').attr('title'),
        gotoslide   = key + 1;

    if(settings.animtype === 'slide'){
        // + 2 to account for clones
        gotoslide = key + 2;
    }

    var marker = $('<li><a href="#">'+ slidename +'</a></li>');
```

From what I can tell the basic html should be this:

```
<li class="bjqs-slide">
    <img src="img/banner01.jpg" title="Automatically generated caption">
    <p class="bjqs-caption">Automatically generated caption</p>
</li>
```

And here's a [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/23GvY/)

Comment: You can also check the js for this line - `conf_captions` - it shows how they grab captions.

Comment: thanks for your answer I really appreciate it.
it returns undefined in the navigation.

Comment: @Sonyflat oops - i see the problem. Need to remove the li. See the updated code.

Comment: Exactly, Thank you very much for all your kindness (going to github looking for the code &..) I truly appreciate it.